# Ms Sql Stored Procedure Using Not Null Syntax

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use stored procedure in my project.So i have question about using **!=(not null)**.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CEP_TELEFONU_NUMARA_LISTESI_GETIR]

AS
BEGIN

SELECT dbo.MUSTERILER_YETKILI.MUSTERILER_ID,MUSTERILER_YETKILI_CEP_TEL 
FROM MUSTERILER_YETKILI 

INNER JOIN MUSTERILER on dbo.MUSTERILER_YETKILI.MUSTERILER_ID=dbo.MUSTERILER.MUSTERILER_ID
AND
dbo.MUSTERILER.MUSTERI_DURUMU=1

ORDER BY MUSTERILER_YETKILI_CEP_TEL
END
```

I want to select datas **if not null**.

Comment: What column should not be null? Use `where your_column is not null`

Comment: Also [don't use the `sp_` prefix](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: This is seriously one for Google. The first result searching for "sql server null" is: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx.

Comment: Also do not like ALLCAPS... hard to read! I think you can benefit greatly from @AaronBertrand's best practice writeup.  https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite your SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CEP_TELEFONU_NUMARA_LISTESI_GETIR]
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT dbo.MUSTERILER_YETKILI.MUSTERILER_ID,MUSTERILER_YETKILI_CEP_TEL 
  FROM MUSTERILER_YETKILI y
  INNER JOIN MUSTERILER m
    on y.MUSTERILER_ID=m.MUSTERILER_ID
  WHERE m.MUSTERI_DURUMU=1
  AND columnnotnullable IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY MUSTERILER_YETKILI_CEP_TEL
END
```

Dear, 
I've changed your inner join condition, because m.MUSTERI_DURUMU = 1 not link two tables but is a filter condition (you can use that in INNER JOIN clause, but if you use an OUTER the result changes if you put a condition in WHERE or ON clause)

I've added

```
AND columnnotnullable IS NOT NULL
```

. This condition filters the results considering a column valued (not null), Please explicit which column name you want to consider as not null.

Finally, I've aliased your table (m and y), instead repeat complete name of your table, you can use an alias, so your query is more readable.